# Shell script that will do the summation of specific attribute present in data

Tags: json, shell

I need to develop shell script that will use the below data and do the summation of the attributes `attribute_x_count`, `attribute_y_count` and `attribute_z_count` only. I am new to shell scripting.

Could you please provide steps that required for creating shell script to
obtain summation of these attributes?

```
{
    "data_type": "dummy",
    "data": {
        "start_time": "2016-05-20",
        "attribute_a": [0, 0, 0, 0],
        "attribute_b": [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
        "attribute_x_count": [0, 0, 1, 1],
        "attribute_y_count": [0, 0, 2, 3],
        "attribute_d": {
            "sub_attribute_p": [0, 0, 0, 0],
            "sub_attribute_q": [0, 0, 0, 0],
            "sub_attribute_r": [0, 0, 0, 0],
            "sub_attribute_s": [0, 0, 0, 0]
        },
        "attribute_e": [0, 0, 0, 0],
        "attribute_f": [0, 0, 0, 0],
        "end_time": "2016-05-21",
        "attribute_z_count": [0, 0, 2, 2],
        "attribute_g": [0, 0, 0, 0],        
        "attribute_i": [0, 0, 0, 0],
        "attribute_j": [0, 0, 0, 0],
        "attribute_k": [0, 0, 0, 0],
        "attribute_i": [3, 0, 0, 0]
    }
}
```

Expected output:-

> Sum (attribute_x/y/z_count) = [0, 0, 1, 1] + [0, 0, 2, 3] + [0, 0, 2,
>   2]
>                           = 2 + 5 + 4 = 11

Comment: @Suraj Sukale Things like "hello" and "thank you" are [considered noise](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) and should be removed when editing, not added. *Especially* not if there already is a "thank you"...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @BenjaminW

Comment: @PrafullaN - you want sum of values `[0, 0, 2, 3]` i.e. `5`?

Comment: I need sum of "attribute_c_count" which appears multiple times. in above case its appeared 3 times. So I need sum like sum = [0, 0, 1, 1] + [0, 0, 2, 3] +[0, 0, 2, 2] that will be 2 + 5 + 4 =11

Comment: check out my answer, if that fits your requirements?

Comment: @ syadav - I tried to run the command which you have but its returning the blank output

Comment: @PrafullaN - you need to make sure input.txt has above content only.

Answer (score 1):

The data is in JSON format, which means that we should be using a JSON parser to work with it. *No, you should not write your own parser, that would be silly.*

I'm using `jq`, which is a "[Command-line JSON processor](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)".

In JSON, if you have multiple attributes with the same name (`attribute_c_count` is an attribute of `data`, which occurs three times (if this is unintentional, whatever code generated the JSON has a bug and *needs to be fixed*)), the value of the *last* one is what counts.

So we can extract the array that need so be summed up like this:

```
$ jq ".data.attribute_c_count" <indata.json
[
  0,
  0,
  2,
  2
]
```

This can be summed up by applying the `add` operation to it:

```
$ jq ".data.attribute_c_count | add" <indata.json
4
```

**EDIT**: The question was modified, and now asks to sum the values of `attribute_x_count`, `attribute_y_count` and `attribute_z_count`.

This will extract the tree arrays:

```
$ jq ".data.attribute_x_count,.data.attribute_y_count,.data.attribute_z_count" <indata.json
[
  0,
  0,
  1,
  1
]
[
  0,
  0,
  2,
  3
]
[
  0,
  0,
  2,
  2
]
```

I'm using `add` to concatenate them into one array, and then `add` again to sum them:

```
$ jq "[.data.attribute_x_count,.data.attribute_y_count,.data.attribute_z_count]|add|add" <indata.json
11
```

(The extra `[...]` is to get an array for the second `add`, otherwise I would just get numbers (try it))

Answer (score 0):

If sum of values `[0, 0, 2, 3]` i.e. `5` is required, then below command can be used, Initially `attribute_c_count` attribute sum was required.

```
grep attribute_c_count input.txt|cut -d: -f2|sed -e 's/\[//g' -e 's/\],//g'|tr ',' '\n'|awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum}
```

**EDIT** 
After different requirement posted by OP.Edited answer. now `attribute_x_count, attribute_y_count and attribute_z_count` attributes sum is required.

```
grep -e attribute_x_count  -e attribute_y_count -e attribute_z_count input.txt|cut -d: -f2|sed -e 's/\[//g' -e 's/\],//g'|tr ',' '\n'|awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it's not quite clear, do you expect to print all the arrays before summing up, or is it the only total value would be sufficient.

In the latter case, using awk, it can be something like

```
gawk -F '[][,]' '/attribute_[xyz]_count/ { for(i = 2; i < NF; ++i) sum += $i }
END { print sum }'
```