# Need to find value that is appearing after particular string using shell script and do the summation

Tags: shell, awk, sed, sum, sh

I am new to shell scripting and I need to find out a value that is appearing after a particular string using shell script and do the summation.

In my use case, I need to find a particular string from a log file.

Now here, I am having two scenario.

**Scenario 1:** "abc" is appearing as single value, i.e., "attribute_1_abc" after that its value which None or any integer value.

**Scenario 2:** "abc" is appearing as list, i.e. abc': {'122': 0, '80': 1, 70': 3}
In this scenario, I need to take the values from list i.e. 0 from '122',
1 from '80' and so on.

Below is part of logs generated for one record processing and we have multiple such records in log file.

---

```
None, 'some_value': None}}},'data': {'metrics': {'attribute_1_abc': 12, 'attribute_2_abc': 0, 'abc': {'122': 0, '80': 1, '72': 2}, 'attribute_3_abc': None}}}
```

**Expected output:**

sum (abc) = value of 'attribute_1_abc' + value of 'attribute_2_abc' + value of 'attribute_3_abc' + sum (abc_list)
 = 12 + 0 + None + 3 = 15

Where sum (abc_list) = 0 + 1 + 2 = 3

Comment: This looks like botched JSON. Why don't you give us the complete JSON document? Also, I answered a _eerily_ similar question to this yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37894097/4941495

Comment: This is part of log file and complete log file is in text format i.e. it has other application information along with above data. So here, I need to retrieve the above data from log file and then do the summation